# undefined method `update_attributes'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have look around and I'm not sure how to fix this problem. I have a undefined method `update_attributes'. I'm thinking it's because @user is not defined. So if I am able to define @user it should be able to fix it. The thing is I don't know how to define @user in order to fix it. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Users.controller.rb:

```
   def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def update
     @user.update_attributes(params[:id])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using restful paths for your resources then update action should be something like this:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

We essentially first find the user record through the params[:id] and then update the user fields.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. What I originally did wrong (the code previous to the one I submitted here on Stack) was had :id and :user switch around in the wrong places. You placed them in the proper order for me. Thanks